# IText7 - IText7 is Not Properly Drawing SVG Documents

Tags: c#, svg, .net-core, itext, itext7

**Project Information :** .NETCore v3.1 - IText7 v7.1.11

We have a PDF Document builder library created by IText7 nuget package, where we can dynamically building large PDF files for our customers.

Normally we are working with `.jpg` format but a new feature is added to our online side which is we have started to work with also interactive `SVG` files with hotspots integrated to our UI.

So, when our application builds a PDF Document it also needs to import those SVG files, we can use it by:

```
var image = SvgConverter.ConvertToImage(
                    new FileStream(imagePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read), pdfDocument);
```

The Original File (I can't upload a SVG so I am uploading as jpg but this is not important because I just want to show the line thickness):

[image: Input]

Output is shown below, as you can see on the left side the lines become very thick and parts are not shown as expected.

[image: Output]

**Steps:**

- SvgConverter.DrawOnCanvas(svgStream, pdfCanvas);
- SvgConverter.DrawOnDocument(svgStream, pdfDocument);
- SvgConverter.DrawOnPage(svgStream, pdfPage);
- SvgConverter.ConvertToXObject(svgStream, pdfDocument);
- SvgConverter.ConvertToImage(svgStream, pdfDocument);

I have tried them all but results are same for all.

**Questions:**

- PDF and SVG files are vectors, so can't we use them as integrated through IText, why should we need to convert it to a Raster? Why do we need a converter?
- Is there a way to decrease thickness or a way to not to lose image quality?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

When you invoke `SvgConverter.ConvertToImage` or `SvgConverter.ConvertToXObject`, your SVG is not converted into a raster image - it still remains a vector image. So you can use the integrated SVG converter workflow and you are in fact using it with the `SvgConverter`. The converter is needed to process SVG file format into more PDF-specific structures, so it performs some conversion because PDF does not support SVG directly. This is not vector -> raster conversion though.

Regarding the problem with the line thickness, first think you should do is to try with the latest version - as far as I see you are trying with 7.1.11 while it's dated back to around a year and 7.1.15 is out already. If the problem persists then it's a bug in the SVG support in iText and you can try to minimize the SVG file to see if there is a workaround to achieve proper conversion until the bug is fixed for your case and/or report the problem to iText (StackOverflow is not the right place to report bugs).

Comment: Hello dear Alexey, thank you for your time, I will first try to upgrade version to 7.1.15 and try this method again. Is 7.1.15 is fully compatible with .Net Core 3.1 ?

Comment: @Burak yes, it is

Comment: Hello @Alexey, we did try to reproduce this issue with IText v7.1.15, but the problem persists. So we'd like to report an issue on IText, can you please guide me?